# PyQt5: TypeError: 'Wrong base class of toplevel widget'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have created to .ui files using QtDesigner and I load them into two seperate windows as show below

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()

        # Set up the user interface from Designer.
        uic.loadUi("interface/UI/main.ui", self)

        # Connect up the buttons
        self.button_classes.clicked.connect(self.open_classes)

        self.w = []

    def open_classes(self):
        self.w.append(PopupWindow(self))
        self.w[-1].show()


class PopupWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()

        # Set up the user interface from Designer.
        uic.loadUi("interface/UI/newclass.ui", self)
```

When I run the code in PyCharm in debug mode, the following error occurs, however this does not happen when the code is run normally

```
TypeError: ('Wrong base class of toplevel widget', (<class 'controllers.GUI.PopupWindow'>, 'QDialog'))
```

Comment: Do you get error message when you run it in console/terminal/cmd.exe/powershell ? add full error message in question.

Comment: @furas When I just run the code normally, there are no errors, however if I run the code in debug mode in PyCharm I get a Type Error that I've added to the question

Comment: you have message `'Wrong base class of toplevel widget', (<class 'controllers.GUI.NewClassWindow'>, 'QDialog'))` so I think it expects you use `QDialog` to create second window but you use `QMainWindow` in `class PopupWindowONE(QMainWindow):`

Comment: @furas Thank you very much for your help, changing `class PopupWindowONE(QMainWindow)` to `class PopupWindowONE(QDialog)` solved the problem. I believe this was caused as I selected the "Dialog with buttons" template in QtDesigner. I've changed the question to properly reflect the problem if you would like to answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have `QDialog` in message `'Wrong base class of toplevel widget', (<class 'controllers.GUI.NewClassWindow'>, 'QDialog')` so I think it expects `QDialog` to create second window but you use `QMainWindow` in `class PopupWindowONE(QMainWindow):`

In other words, check the class type of the .ui file you are going to initiate; if the class is a `QDialog` then your python class needs to receive a `QDialog`.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem when using `QDialog` but changed it to `QMainWindow` and it worked.